# Error when refreshing list box when one of its item is highlighted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I am currently working on a project that has a list box that represents players connected to a server. I templated the list box items so that they contain the picture of the player and its name, with a grey border appearing around those elements when the mouse enters the area.

My problem is that if a user has the mouse over one of the list box items when that list gets updated (let's say when a new user connects to the server), Visual Studio throws an error that concerns my mouse over mechanics, telling me it cannot find a name in XAML.

Here's my list box item template

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <Border  BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2,2,0,0" Cursor="Hand">

            <Border.BorderBrush  >
                <SolidColorBrush   x:Name="BorderBackgroundColor" /> 
            </Border.BorderBrush >

            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush  x:Name="GridBackgroundColor"  />
                </Grid.Background>

                <Grid.Triggers >
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter" >
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="GridBackgroundColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"  To="Gray" />
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackgroundColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"  To="Gray" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseLeave" >
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="GridBackgroundColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"  To="Transparent" />
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackgroundColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"  To="Transparent" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Grid.Triggers>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition   />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Height="30"  >
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StateToBorderConverter}" >
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"  />
                            <Binding  Path="State" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>

                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=imagePath}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </Border>

                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=profileName}"  VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here's the refresh method

```
    private void ActualisePlayerList( PlayerListMessage playerListMessage )
    {
        playersProfileInfo.Clear();

        foreach (Utilitaire.ClientProperties oneProperty in playerListMessage.Clients)
        {
            string profileName = oneProperty.Username;
            string imagePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "//Profile" + oneProperty.Username.ToLower() + ".jpg";
            if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                imagePath = "ImageRessources/anonymous-icon.jpg";
            }
            playersProfileInfo.Add(new ProfileContainer(imagePath, profileName, oneProperty.State));
        }

       PlayersListBox.ItemsSource = playersProfileInfo; 
       PlayersListBox.Items.Refresh();

       Filter("");
    }
```

Here's the order being thrown

```
 Cannot find the name 'GridBackgroundColor' in the name range of 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'.
```

As previously mentionned, the error is triggered just after the call to ActualisePlayerList. That error description is translated, so please tell me if it doesn't ring any bells. Anyways, any ideas why it shows up ? Is there something I don't know about triggers on templated list box items ? Could it be that the fade out animation is being called when the item is already removed ? How can I make this work ?

Comment: Instead of using `EventTriggers`, use `DataTrigger`s against the `IsMouseOver` property.

Comment: How exactly would I assign the IsMouseOver proprety to the DataTrigger ? Do I need to use Binding to link it to another element that has IsMouseOver as a proprety ?

Comment: <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid,Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SelectionGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </DataTrigger>`   
            That's an example

Comment: did you write ClientProperties class?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with how you are refreshing the list.  Instead of clearing the list and reassigning the ItemsSource, you should try setting the ItemsSource once and then just manipulating the data within it.  If you use `ObservableCollection<>` as the source, you don't have to call any `Refresh()`.  The refresh will occur automatically.

Comment: The Refresh() was there as a precaution, but I removed it and the ItemsSource affectation and it did not change the error.

Comment: You changed the itemssource data type to ObservableCollection too?

Comment: If you use ObservableCollection<> it updates the listBox when item removed or added to the list. Nothing happens if change occurs on one of the existing items.

Comment: Getting stuff to update is simply a matter of implementing notifypropertychange